# NotificationHub: What happens if duplicate installations are created with the same PNS handle?

Tags: c#, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

Suppose that I create an installation with `NotificationHub` like so:

```
var installation = new Installation
{
    InstallationId = installationId,
    PushChannel = pnsHandle
};

await NotificationHubClient.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(installation);
```

and run two consecutive executions with the following values:

**First:**

InstallationId => A

PushChannel => X

**Second:**

InstallationId => B

PushChannel => X

Will Azure remove the first installation and overwrite it by the second? Therefore, Installation A will no longer exist?

Comment: What happened when you tested it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notification Hub will allow you to create multiple installations with the same PushChannel. It will ultimately create two separate installations.

One caveat though, when creating a push to send to those devices, Notification Hub will de-duplicate based on the PushChannel, so it will actually detect that those are the same device and intentionally not send a duplicate push to the user.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. Consider the following scenario: User A and User B register the same PushChannel (let's say one logs out and the other creates a new account on the same device). Due to some activity, I decide to send a push to User A via User A's `InstallationId` but User B is currently logged in. Will User B get User A's notification?

Comment: Assuming the PushChannel doesn't change, the second user will indeed receive the first user's notifications. However, if they change accounts at the Android level (assuming you're using FCM) that account should be associated with a different PushChannel.

Comment: @MarStr Do you guys have any plans to remedy this problem? I'm now thinking of creating a database table whose primary key is the PushChannel so that I know to delete existing installations when a key violation happens to avoid duplicate installations. Do you think this is a good workaround?

Comment: Our usual remedy for this problem is to lean on OS specific authentication, and to have a single user associated with a push channel. :) For that reason, we don't have plans to change our story. However, I understand your scenario. I think the work around of deleting Installation could make sense for you, though because I'm not working with you on the app, I don't feel like I can comment on whether storing that information on the device or in a DB makes mores sense.

Comment: Can't store anything on the device. DB makes more sense in my scenario. Thanks for the discussion.